# Android requestFeature() window exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-windowmanager

After going through all other threads on ***requestFeature() must be called before adding content*** I'm posting this question here as a last resort.

I have an activity(extended from a BaseActivity) with **windowActionBarOverlay** set in Manifest declaration, **not programmatically using requestFeature()** method. Also activity handles configuration changes.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.spuul.android.activity.VideoDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/activity_title_movies"
        android:parentActivityName="com.spuul.android.activity.BrowseActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SynopsisTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.spuul.android.activity.BrowseActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And theme in style looks like:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_bg</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="SynopsisTheme" parent="@style/BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Yet I see lots of requestFeature() crashes on my Crashlytics portal and  worst part is I couldn't reproduce this issue on my test devices. Hoping someone could point me in right direction. here is the stackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spuul.android/com.spuul.android.activity.VideoDetailsActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)                          Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:320)
   at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3338)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:62)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
   at com.spuul.android.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:104)
   at com.spuul.android.activity.VideoDetailsActivity.onCreate(VideoDetailsActivity.java:222)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

UPDATE:
Here is the activity code -
VideoDetailsActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.synopsis_activity_layout);
    // Activity UI logic follows
}
```

BaseActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar()
                .setDisplayOptions(
                        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        ise.printStackTrace();
        if (LogUtil.LOG) LogUtil.e(TAG, "action bar is not supported with this theme..");
    } 
    if (isTablet) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

And there is a player fragment, which sets orientation based on user preference from player controls. I don't think that will have an impact, because orientation is handled by activity already. And more over from crash logs it looks like problem occurs while intializing activity or it could be while recreating it. Any idea on how to deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just remove the line request feature from onCreate of activity, it will work

Comment: @TheGreat004  **not programmatically using requestFeature() method.**

Comment: The buddy post the activity code

Comment: There is not enough information to help you, we would be guessing. We need to see what is in your on onCreate() (that is relevant).

Comment: @JoxTraex Added activity code. Thanks